# Testing redirects to parameterized URLs when creating object

Tags: python, django, django-testing, pytest-django

I have a view for creating blog posts which redirects the user to a form to fill the blog post content like this:

```py
from django.views import View
from app.models import BlogPost

class CreateBlogPost(View):
    def post():
        new_post = BlogPost.objects.create()
        return redirect(reverse('post_edit'), args=[new_post.id])


class EditBlogPost(View):
    ...
```

And my urls are the following:

```py
from django.urls import path
from app.views import CreateBlogPost

urlpatterns = [
    path('post', CreateBlogPost.as_view(), name='post_create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/edit', EditBlogPost.as_view(), name='post_edit')
]
```

I would like to: test the CreateBlogPost by asserting that it redirects to `post/<some_id>/edit`.

I've tried: using the method `assertRedirects` from django's `SimpleTestCase`, but couldn't find a way to make this work.

I'm also using pytest-django, in case that's relevant.

Comment: U must have to use TestCase and it would be like that..!